# How to Save an Image from Nokia Imaging SDK

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I am having issues with some sample code that I am using from one of Nokia's Imaging SDK samples they provide. Essentially I am trying to save an image to IsolatedStorage. The code that I am reusing has been used successfully elsewhere in the solution, but when I try to use it there are no errors but it does not proceed with the following statements. Essentially in the `StorePhoto` method, once `IBuffer buffer = await App.PhotoModel.RenderFullBufferAsync();` is called no error occurs but no code below that which is actually performs the save to isolated storage operation is ran, so no image is ever saved.

SavePage.xaml.cs

```
private static string _photoModelPath = @"\Lockscreen\v1\PhotoModel";
private static string _photoModelBufferFilename = @"buffer.data";

public async static void StorePhoto()
    {
        string _photoModelPath = @"\Lockscreen\v1\LockScreen";
        string _photoModelBufferFilename = @"buffer.data";

        using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (!storage.DirectoryExists(_photoModelPath))
            {
                storage.CreateDirectory(_photoModelPath);
            }

            if (storage.FileExists(_photoModelPath + @"\" + _photoModelBufferFilename))
            {
                storage.DeleteFile(_photoModelPath + @"\" + _photoModelBufferFilename);
            }

            IBuffer buffer = await App.PhotoModel.RenderFullBufferAsync();  //code exiting method with no error

            if (buffer != null)
            {
                IsolatedStorageFileStream originalFile = storage.CreateFile(_photoModelPath + @"\" + _photoModelBufferFilename);

                Stream bufferStream = buffer.AsStream();

                bufferStream.CopyTo(originalFile);
                bufferStream.Flush();
                bufferStream.Close();
                bufferStream.Dispose();

                originalFile.Flush();
                originalFile.Close();
                originalFile.Dispose();
            }                  
        }
    }
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private async void _saveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Helpers.SaveHelper.StorePhoto(); //calling the StorePhoto method here
    }
```

PhotoModel.cs (from Nokia Imaging SDK sample)

```
/// <summary>
    /// Renders current image with applied filters to a buffer and returns it.
    /// Meant to be used where the filtered image is for example going to be
    /// saved to a file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Buffer containing the filtered image data</returns>
    public async Task<IBuffer> RenderFullBufferAsync()
    {
        using (BufferImageSource source = new BufferImageSource(_buffer))
        using (FilterEffect effect = new FilterEffect(source) { Filters = _components })
        using (JpegRenderer renderer = new JpegRenderer(effect))
        {
            return await renderer.RenderAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to solve this I had to put the code that saves the image into the same page that I was originally calling that method, and also it needs to be of type Task so that the async/await will work properly.

Comment: The code should work elsewhere in the project, putting it in a helper/utility class should not be a problem. The problem is that you did not await your call to StorePhoto() from _saveItem_Click. So making it a async Task method is the way to go, then awaiting the call.